# how to reverse shapekey with only 1 shapekey (VRM)

Tags: modeling, rigging, shape-keys

Okay so I'm currently working on a VRM rig right now, so I want to flip the mouth -180 however when I open instead of going in a similar direction, it goes to its original position, for a better explanation here's a video
https://youtu.be/--3-PEF0V9g
blend file as well to make it easier
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bZD9rlov-LTmt89oLyuITRfAjfNUSQko/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try varying Range min and max values of the shape keys: default is from 0.0 to 1.0, but they can be set from - 2.0 to 2.0, and maybe reach your goal in this simple way.